# Type fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory during Eclipse (Oxygen) compilation

Tags: c, eclipse, header, gtk

I've some errors compiling C code with GTK widgets in Eclipse, indicating that gtk/gtk.h cannot be found. I've already installed GTK+2 and GTK+3; and also included the header paths for GTK but it seems that the Eclipse environment is still unable to find the required header.

Greatly appreciate any advice from the community!

Comment: There's no such thing as a *C script*, although the definition of a *scripting language* has some ambiguities, C definitely isn't one.

Comment: Regarding your question, the problem isn't directly related to programming. I **guess** you're using some linux distribution, they typically have separate packages for the files needed to compile code using a library, something called similar to `gtk-dev`, `libgtk-dev` `libgtk2-development`, ... -> search for it in your package manager.

Comment: @FelixPalmen. Yes indeed, i've amended the err. to be C code instead. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04LTS. Let me try out.

Comment: actually still the same problem. i went to terminal and used gcc to compile, and also met with the same problem, i.e. gtk/gtk.h can't be found during compilation.

Comment: Did you check the file **actually exists** on your machine?

Comment: yeah, i went into /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk and also /usr/include/gtk-2.0/gtk to open up the header file. Just seems like the header file couldn't be found during compilation.

Comment: add `-I/usr/include/gtk-2.0` or  `-I/usr/include/gtk-3.0` to your compiler command line.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide enough information to actually know what is going on, but I guess the include paths you configured are somehow wrong.

My advice would be that you should use [pkg-config](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/) to obtain the correct compiler flags instead of adding include dirs etc. manually.

This will give you a list of all packages, pkg-config knows are installed on your machine:

```
pkg-config --list-all
```

The GTK package should be something like `gtk+-3.0`

Use this to get the CFLAGS for use with GTK3:

```
pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0
```

And here is how to get the libraries for the linker stage:

```
pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0
```

So instead of doing something like this:

```
# Don't do this
gcc -I... main.c
```

... use something like this:

```
gcc $(pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0) ... main.c
```

Read the man page of pkg-config for more informations.

There was an Eclipse plugin for pkg-config support, but it doesn't seem to work with Oxygen. I managed to get a building example with these settings, though Eclipse itself won't find the includes.

[image: Compiler settings]
[image: Linker settings]